# Final Fantasy 12 weapons cheats using PCSX2 emulator?

Tags: cheats, final-fantasy-12

I'm using PCSX2 0.9.9 to emulate [Final Fantasy 12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XII). I've being using some cheats for experience, status, drop rate and license points through a [.pnach](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-How-pnach-files-work) file.

Does anyone know about weapons cheats using this kind of file?

Comment: I think this is off-topic as a recommendation (see the [FAQ]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for :

```
Have all Weapons (CB2v7+)
1054E82A 00000063
4054E82C 00500001
00630063 00000000
1054E978 00000063
1054E982 00000063
40553A4C 004F0001
10021001 00020002
20553B88 10A810A0
10553B8C 000010AD
005548BC 000000A1
```

Get them all here : http://www.ff12sector.com/ff12_gameshark_codebreaker_codes.php